# Complete HTML in notify.js

Tags: javascript, notifyjs

I am using library [Notify js](https://notifyjs.jpillora.com/) for showing success or error messages on my php web page.
When I use normal text like

```
$.notify("Changes are made successfully", "success");
```

Then it works fine.

But sometimes, I need to show message in unordered list like as follows:

```
var message = '<p> Please correct following errors and then try again </p><ul><li>value1 is wrong</li><li>value 3 is wrong</li><li>value 5 is wrong</li></ul>';
$.notify(message, "error");
```

Then message is shown as it is, means whole html is displaying, instead I want to display like

```
Please correct following errors and then try again

 - value1 is wrong
 - value3 is wrong
 - value5 is wrong
```

Any suggestion would be highly appreciated!

Comment: https://github.com/jpillora/notifyjs/issues/63 IIRC you either have to use the custom styling, or tweak the library.

Comment: If you want to show arbitraty HTML (less secure than using *text*) content inside an element, the `data-notify-html` attribute should be used on that element. As stated in the DOCS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can add an own Class with the HTML Content like a Template System.

```
$.notify.addStyle('saved', {
  html: 
    "<p>Saved blabla...</p>"
});

$.notify(..., { 
  style: 'saved'
});
```

Comment: I totally missed that one! Good job!

Comment: @Jan Heil:- It is working perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

Other two ways (beside the utterly noisy `addStyle` method)

### Use `\n` *newline* escape character

use `\n` and expect `<br>`! Therefore instead of using UL > LI use just some combination of *newline* escapes `\n` like:

Store your possible errors inside an Array and than simply use then inside the Notify mesage:

```js
const errors = [ // Or however you can push() errors into this array...
  "value 1 is wrong",
  "value 2 is wrong",
  "value 3 is wrong",
];

// Add dashs "-" to each error and join with newline
const errorsList = errors.map(err => ` - ${err}`).join("\n");
const message = `Please correct following errors and then try again\n\n${errors.join("\n")}`;
$.notify(message, "error");
```

which will result in:

```
Please correct following errors and then try again

 - value 1 is wrong
 - value 2 is wrong
 - value 3 is wrong
```

### Modify the plugin source

A simple edit to the source code to allow for **HTML** is:

at line 205 add to the `pluginOptions`:

```js
        encode: true,
```

at line 513 change `d = encode(d);` to be:

```js
                if (this.options.encode) {
                    d = encode(d);
                }
```

Finally, when you use the plugin simply set the new Option `encode` to `false`:

```js
// Use like:
$.notify("Lorem<br><b>Ipsum</b>", {encode: false});
```

Here's my [pull request](https://github.com/jpillora/notifyjs/pull/139) related to [this Issue#130](https://github.com/jpillora/notifyjs/issues/130)

Comment: Thanks for suggestion of using `data-notify-html`, but how to use it, it is not clearly mentioned how to use it? Can you give an example about its usage?

Comment: @Ishpreet I believe it should be like: `<div id="myNotify" data-notify-html></div>`.

Comment: means if I pass message like `const message = <div id="myNotify" data-notify-html><p>Please correct following errors and then try again</p><ul><li>Value is wrong</li></ul></div>`, then it will work?

Comment: @Ishpreet I know only what the documentation says. And that's to add that `data-*` attribute to the element you use to show your notifications.

Comment: @Ishpreet edited with a solution. (Yeah I could not either make it work by using that `data-*` attribute as well :( )

Comment: I have also seen this method, but docs have not explained with example. Just mentioned that use `data-notify-html`, but didn't help me. That's why I asked in SO.

Comment: @Ishpreet added additionally the needed changes to the plugin to make it work with HTML.

Comment: @Ishpreet here's the pull request https://github.com/jpillora/notifyjs/pull/139

Comment: Your solution may also work, but this solution is type of touching library's js files. Jan Heil has exactly fitted my HTML message in easy way. Thanks a lot for your support.

Comment: @Ishpreet well the code is meant to be touched. (I've provided a pull request). But yeah, if a method already exists, than seems simpler that way. Even though I find it too clumsy.